# video.js: force initialization of already manually initialized video

Tags: javascript, initialization, embed, video.js

I'm dynamically generating and changing the content of my site with javascript.
I'm adding video files and the videojs-javascript-files by javascript and initialize the video by calling `_V_(videos[i].id);`.
However, initializing the video only works at the **first time**!
When I then change the content of the site and then move to the video's page again, initializing the video again (the video-tag has still the same id) does not work.
The browser's HTML5 videoplayer is there but not the videojs-styled one.

Is there any other way I could "force" initialization of the player? What could cause this problem?

This is my script:

```
videoPlayer = {
    check: function() {
        videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
        if (videos.length > 0) {
            this.init();
        }
    },
    init: function() {
        if (isPlayer) {
            //alert("init");
            for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) var player = _V_(videos[i].id, {}, function() {
                alert("player init!")
            });
        }
        else {
            this.build();
        }
    },
    build: function() {
        //alert("build");
        if (isPlayer == false) {
            var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            var videoScript = document.createElement('script');
            videoScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            videoScript.src = './min/g=videojs';
            var videocss = document.createElement('link');
            videocss.type = 'text/css';
            videocss.rel = 'stylesheet';
            videocss.href = './min/g=videocss';
            isPlayer = true;
            videoScript.onload = this.init;
            head.appendChild(videocss);
            head.appendChild(videoScript);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new video element and (re)initializing it instead of re-using the previous video element?

You can also try to "reset" everything, src, tracks, captions, etc with the new values

Answer (score 0):

I know it's pretty late, but you could try checking the children of the video element. For example, if it already contains a div of class vjs-poster do nothing, else initialize video-js.